# ExtJS Items still appearing despite code being removed

Tags: javascript, browser, extjs

I'm having an issue where I have deleted code that called an ajax request & displayed a message box in a grid but it is still showing in the browser.

Someone else tried it and it's showing the change for them.

I am using Eclipse & cleaned, rebuilt, removed/readded & restarted my project. I have also cleared all cache/browser hsitory from my browser & tried removing & readding the file to project. None of which have resolved the issue.

The function is being called from an image hyperlink which is being displayed in the grid. That code has not changed, only the underlying function.

This is the actual code in the file:

```
function getReport(type, date){

    alert(type);
    alert(date);
}
```

This is the code shown in Firebug:

```
function getReport(type, date){

alert(type);
alert(date);

Ext.Ajax.request({
url: 'cxf/rest/ws/getX',
method: 'POST',
timeout:180000,
params: {Type: type, Date: date},
success: function(){
 var grid = Ext.getCmp('oGrid');
grid.getStore().reload();
},
failure: function(){
 alert('Unable to retrieve the report. Please contact the System Administrator');
 }
 });

}
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I have the same setup as the other person who tried it & this is the first time any JS changes have not appeared.

Comment: Have you tried in a different browser?

Comment: yes, tried it in IE as well but still getting the same issue

Comment: Any chance that the same code is written in 2 functions and you've removed it from one and the other function is called? The scenario might be different when the other user tested it, hence the function which doesn't contain the code might be executing.

Comment: I had thought about that and went through my code & removed any ajax requests to see if that made a difference but it didn't. Other JS files have the same function but even when I commented out code from them, it didn't help.

Comment: try disabling firebug and run it again.

Comment: that made no difference. still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you clear your cache?  Is there a proxy cache in play?

Open up firebug and see where the code is on the js files. Add break points and see what is called. Track down the problem.

Use fiddler to see the http requests if needed.

Comment: I cleared all cache from both browsers. It's possible that there may be a default proxy cache but I have no idea where I would find this or identify if it exists. I am using Eclipse/Tomcat with the default settings.

Comment: Whoops this was supposed to be a comment not an answer . I need my morning coffee.

Comment: There is something weird in that if I open the JS file in the URL, it shows the new code but in Firebug, under the script tab, it shows the old code.

Comment: There is a bug that sometimes the js files get stuck http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=36 Try clearing the cache [clear private data], close browser, and reopen.

Answer (score 0):

In Firebug, open the Firebug menu (top left, picture of a fiery bug) and select "Deactivate Firebug for this site". This is different in some special way from just closing Firebug, which I see you've already done.